# I use Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04, but I continue to get security updates for Firefox

Tags: package-management, updates, firefox, 18.04

Google Chrome works fine, and I uninstalled Firefox, but I continue to get security updates for Firefox. I ran `autoremove` after uninstalling Firefox, but that didn't help. This isn't a problem, just a  question out of curiosity.

Comment: You probably didn't remove all firefox packages.

Comment: Possibly `xul-ext-ubufox` and the "locale" for your system language such as `firefox-locale-en`. Specifying the "security updates for firefox" would make things clear.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge as I am relatively new to ubuntu, but how would I go about removing the above-mentioned packages?

Comment: @Brian What happens when you run `apt list firefox* | grep installed`?

Comment: Type `locate firefox` and let us know if anything pops up.

Comment: The security updates (and all others updates) of firefox comes from the ppa, and `apt autoremove` didn't removed it, so if you deleted the ppa, you won't get ANY updates from firefox (but I can be wrong because firefox can be in a general ppa)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' '*firefox*' 'xul-ext-*' | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs apt-cache policy`? Thanks.

Comment: after running apt list firefox* | grep installed I receive the following:                                apt list firefox* | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

firefox-locale-en/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 61.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]

Comment: Brian, as @Pilot6 pointed out, this package is probably what's prompting the updates. Running `sudo apt-get remove firefox-locale-en` should take care of it.

Comment: Just removed firefox-locale-en. Hopefully that'll fix the problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Ploni maybe you can post that as an answer to mark this is answered.